HttpClient.get retrieving index.html instead of an asset file
When I run the code below locally it works fine.
When it is pushed to server (AWS Amplify) it fails to work correctly.
In the console there is an error:

ERROR Error: Invalid HTML: could not find <table>

Code:
 this.http
      .get("./assets/data/test.txt", { responseType: "text" })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });

When run locally the output is whatever text is inside the file.
When run from the server the output is the HTML of the Angular app.
I tried different file names and response types before discovering that the HTML was being returned.

I am no expert with AWS but I once had a similar issue in which the following URL helped me. https://repost.aws/questions/QURxK3sj5URbCQ8U2REZt7ow/images-not-showing-in-angular-application-on-amplify
We did move our images in S3 but the solution of modifying amplify.yml seems a possible way to fix your issue.
Hope this helps fix your issue.

So, first Thank-You for responding. I think this has to do with amplify redirects mentioned in the resource you provided. However, I don't know how to stop the redirection of HttpClient.Get request for CSV type. I added CSV to the default list in Amplify Console but this did not change anything.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html
